# count $_POST sented

Tags: php, variables, post, count

For example I have 3 variables and I sent 2 of them to result.php

```
$_POST['apple'];
$_POST['peach'];
$_POST['kiwi'];
```

**Q: How can I count posted variables in result page ?**

*note: I don't know how many variables I sent*

Comment: Google: "How can I count posted variables php?", first result `count()`

Comment: I know `count` function, didn't know `$_POST` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php):

```
echo count($_POST);
```